# how do i publish my asp.net project to my local iis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, publish

I've been looking and I've seen a few how-tos but I find them to be somewhat confusing.

Does anyone have a good tutorial or step by step writeup that's easy to follow for a newbie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking to run your application under IIS, [setting up a virtual directory is pretty straightforward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx).  If you're looking to test publish a build, the web deployment project is the way to go (you can do it from the command line and in VS.Net, it enables a "Publish" right-click option).

Answer (score 13):

In Visual Studio, go on project properties > tab web and check "Use Local IIS Web Server". Then, it will ask you to if you want to create the virtual directory, answer yes and vouala...you create a IIS virtual directory, when you run your application, they will run on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be looking into web deployment projects.

This link is for VS2008, but they also exist for VS2005

[VS2008 Web Deployment Project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your web app to an iis website. Click on Build > Publish Web app and select to publish to Local IIS website. Job done.

For a local development environment this is fine but if you want to deploy to a test or staging server than look at another solution such as the Web Deployment project or use nant or msbuild.